# pac-container react autocomplete - how do i reference the CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to change the pac-container for my google autocomplete component. I want to style this pac-container, but I have no idea how to reference the css of the already defined class name.

Here's my code

```
...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            address_ignore_autofill: this.props.address,
        };
        this.autocomplete = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.autocomplete = new 
google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'), {});
        this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", this.handlePlaceSelect)
    }

    handleFormChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ address_ignore_autofill: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <TextField
                onChange={(e) => this.handleFormChange(e)}
            />
        );
    }
```

Where am i supposed to modify `.pac-container?` . I've tried modifying right in `index.css` but that isn't working. I've also tried wrapping my `<Textfield/>` class in a `div`  and doing

```
import './test.css'

<div className='test'>
  <Textfield>
</div>
```

and

`this is test.css`

```
.test .pac-container {
    margin-top: 500
}
```

but that didn't work either.

Doing

```
 .pac-container {
    margin-top: 500
}
```

didn't work either.

I know I'm missing something incredibly stupid. Please help. Thanks

Comment: you need to include the unit in your margin-top value. `margin-top: 500px;`

Comment: I'm having the same issue TODAY. Did you find a solution??

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the unit in your margin-top value

```
.pac-container {
    margin-top: 500px;
}
```